# Does the Catholic Church have an official position on medical passes ('vaccine passes') being required to attend Mass?

Tags: catholicism, mass, covid-19

I have already asked a question about the more general issue of medical passes ('vaccine passes') here

[Does the Catholic Church have an official position on domestic 'health passes' or 'vaccine passes' that could be used to control citizens' activities?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/84217/does-the-catholic-church-have-an-official-position-on-domestic-health-passes-o)

The answer seems to be 'no', the Church has no official position.

These medical passes are now a reality in multiple regions, including the one I live in, and have led to de facto segregation once implemented, preventing anyone who for reasons of conscience decides to opt out of the injections to be barred from basic aspects of civic life. The Church's silence on this speaks volumes.

Yet what about these passes being used as barriers to attending Mass? Does the Catholic Church have any official position on this very real possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Does the Catholic Church have an official position on medical passes (“vaccine passes”) being required to attend Mass?**

The short answer is **no**. I rather doubt that the sacraments or attending Mass will ever be for the double vaccinated only.

As for the moment, the Church encourages the faithful to get vaccinated, but it will never publicly mandate it as a moral obligation. The individual conscience of each of the faithful is to be respected on this issue.

Whether a government will try to mandate such a decree is another matter. That will definitely [*open up a new can of worms*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/open%20a%20can%20of%20worms)!

Rome has already made it clear that the faithful are **not** morally obliged to receive a vaccine.

> At the same time, practical reason makes evident that vaccination is not, as a rule, a moral obligation and that, therefore, it must be voluntary. In any case, from the ethical point of view, the morality of vaccination depends not only on the duty to protect one's own health, but also on the duty to pursue the common good. - [Note on the morality of using some anti-Covid-19 vaccines](https://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/cfaith/documents/rc_con_cfaith_doc_20201221_nota-vaccini-anticovid_en.html)

Thus if the vaccines are looked upon as something voluntary; it makes no sense that the Church would required it for Mass attendance. However, I do fear that governments may try to make it an obligation, in which case the Church will have to defend the rights of the laity in this matter.

The battle line is being set up, so be prepared.

The following articles may be of interest:

- [Can a church pastor prohibit sacraments to people for any reason, other than mortal sin?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/82530/can-a-church-pastor-prohibit-sacraments-to-people-for-any-reason-other-than-mor)
- [Could a Catholic Church minister distribute communion to the community while churches are closed?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/81122/could-a-catholic-church-minister-distribute-communion-to-the-community-while-chu)

**Addendum:**

Even if certain dioceses have made guidelines for their respective dioceses, these guidelines simply involve that particular diocese and are not considered an official position for the Universal Church.

For example the [Diocese of Moncton](http://www.diomoncton.ca/en/news-item/covid-19-green-phase-september-17th-2021-update), New Brunswick requires the faithful to be double vaccinated in order to attend Mass. I would expect this to eventually be challenged in court and at Rome!

Rome could eventually leave this decision to the local ordinaries (Bishops), but at the present moment has not done so.

**Second Addendum:**

Decision rescinded!

On September 24, 2021, the Canadian Archdiocese of Moncton has rescinded a policy that required all Catholics wishing to enter church buildings to show proof of having received two doses of a coronavirus vaccination and record their names with volunteers.

> The new policies appear in line with the Church’s own internal assessment of vaccines and public health protections during the pandemic.
>
> Pope Francis and the Congregation for the Doctrine of the Faith in Rome have made clear that it is morally acceptable for Catholics to receive all of the widely available vaccines against coronavirus, and stated repeatedly that doing so is a service to the common good. The CDF has also insisted that vaccination is a matter of prudential moral freedom for the individual.
>
> The new Moncton policy, now common to all the dioceses of the province, provides that “it is highly desirable for parish employees to be fully vaccinated.” “If this is not the case, they will have to wear a mask at all times and undergo a COVID test periodically according to government policy.”
>
> “We will accept anyone who comes to the parish offices to get information or service. If this person is not vaccinated, they must wear a mask,” the archdiocese said. - [Canadian archdiocese drops vaccine registry for Mass](https://www.pillarcatholic.com/p/canadian-archdiocese-drops-vaccine)

Comment: +1 "for the double vaccinated only" Should probably read 'vaccinated indefinitely every half a year'. https://www.haaretz.com/israel-news/israel-may-deny-green-passports-to-people-who-have-not-received-covid-booster-1.10147312 Note they are referring to the *third* Pfizer shot in this article.

Comment: http://www.diomoncton.ca/en/news-item/covid-19-green-phase-september-17th-2021-update

Comment: @OneGodtheFather [Canadian archdiocese drops vaccine registry for Mass](https://www.pillarcatholic.com/p/canadian-archdiocese-drops-vaccine)

Comment: "I would expect this to eventually be challenged in court and at Rome!" What kind of court are you thinking of? There is no administrative court in the Church besides the way to Rome (and there the Apostolic Signature).

Comment: Please don't use addenda to answers. Answers need to stand alone for years. Just write that the Diocese of Moncton's decision was short-lived.

Comment: Here we go again, this time a Bishop in NL. https://www.lifesitenews.com/news/catholics-must-have-jabs/?utm_source=featured

Answer (score 1):

What is meant by an "official" position? It seems to me that it is fairly clear from the [Note on the morality of using some anti-Covid-19 vaccines](https://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/cfaith/documents/rc_con_cfaith_doc_20201221_nota-vaccini-anticovid_en.html) that the decision to receive a vaccine or not is something that should not be forced upon an individual.

> 5. At the same time, practical reason makes evident that vaccination is not, as a rule, a moral obligation and that, therefore, it must be voluntary.

You can certainly be of the opinion that others should vaccinate, as a Catholic, but you cannot force them to vaccinate, so I don't see how a good Catholic could support vaccine *mandates*, whether in public life or for Mass.

Comment: Ya, but what does 'voluntary' mean. Excluded from basic civic life but still voluntary? Lose your job but still voluntary?

Comment: Voluntary has never meant that violence and coercion are used to make you do something.

Comment: http://www.diomoncton.ca/en/news-item/covid-19-green-phase-september-17th-2021-update

Comment: Sounds like the Archbishop doesn't care about Catholic morals.

Comment: You forgot the rest of the quote. "In any case, from the ethical point of view, the morality of vaccination depends not only on the duty to protect one's own health, but also on the duty to pursue the common good. In the absence of other means to stop or even prevent the epidemic, the common good may recommend vaccination, especially to protect the weakest and most exposed. Those who, however, for reasons of conscience, refuse vaccines produced with cell lines from aborted fetuses, (...)

Comment: (...) must do their utmost to avoid, by other prophylactic means and appropriate behavior, becoming vehicles for the transmission of the infectious agent. In particular, they must avoid any risk to the health of those who cannot be vaccinated for medical or other reasons, and who are the most vulnerable."

Comment: How does that segment pertain to vaccine mandates?